# Images are not showing in ckfinder in eclipse

Tags: html, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have included the CKfinder in my html file. After included this file, I'm able to see the images in folderwise in popup window and able to store the image as well. As per my view, when we click on browse server button, it is creating ckfinder folder and storing all the uploaded images. It is working fine in XAMPP server.

But when I tried to implement the same thing in my Eclipse project, Images folder is not showing. It's showing blank in the popup window.

How to fix this issue? Kindly help me.

Comment: Do you have any code you could include in your question?

Comment: yeah im having the code. How shall I upload the code here. This is open source right. I can upload here for reference

Comment: You just copy the code into your question, making sure that each line is indented by at least 4 spaces. (see [markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)).

Comment: @Tagc: Do you want me to include the full code here or some part?

Comment: I don't mind as I'm not planning to answer this question either way. It's up to your judgement to decide what code to include in order to best allow this community to help you. My recommendation would be to provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).